# How to make a ajax call from local html files inside assets dir of android?

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, call, local

I have an android web app using phonegap and jquery mobile, phonegap.html files have been put into assets dir, and it access data from remote server using $.ajax method, but it does not work.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

eg:

ajax("login.action",....)
 assets/login.html ------------------------->login.action

1. login.html is local file inside assets
2. login.action is remote interface
3. login.html using $.ajax method to fetch data from login.action,but not works!

Sorry, My English is poor!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into the Same Origin Policy restriction (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents cross site scripting.

There are two common solutions.

The older one is JSONP (JSON with padding) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

A newer less invasive solution is CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

Hope that helps.